# Heroku Login Error verify that your path is correct and try again

Tags: heroku

I am using windows 10 64 bit. I installed heroku. After that when I am trying to login from my terminal, it gives me error like this. [click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtOyF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: And please make sure to always include _complete_ error messages. This appears to be the end of a PowerShell error about not being able to find the command you're trying to run. How did you install the CLI? Did you open a _new_ terminal afterwards, or are you still using an old one?